# mismatch in sizes with test and train data during function print

Tags: python, numpy

Data file I would like to process has 71 records build with two columns: one for x value and second one for y value. Main task is to select training part and testing part, print chosen functions (in my example I've taken linear and exponential(^4) one.
However I've stumbled upon error I can't solve.

Full description of the error:

```
File="zad1.py", line 25, in module

v = np.linalg.pinv(c) @ y
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, 
with gufunc signature (n?, k),(k, m?)->(n?,m?) (size 71 is different from 53)
```

code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.loadtxt('dane10.txt')
x = a[:,[1]]
y = a[:,[0]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)
c = np.hstack([X_train, np.ones(X_train.shape)])
v = np.linalg.pinv(c) @ y
plt.plot(X_train, y_train, 'ro')
plt.plot(X_test, y_test, 'go')
plt.plot(X_train,v[0]*X_train + v[1])


c = np.hstack([
   X_train * X_train * X_train * X_train,
   X_train * X_train * X_train,
   X_train * X_train,
   X_train,
   np.ones(X_train.shape)])
v = np.linalg.pinv(c) @ y
plt.plot(v[0]*X_train^4 + v[1]*X_train^3 + v[2]*X_train^2 + v[3]*X_train +v[4])
plt.show()
```

Would appreciate any help :).

I've redone it a little and both functions are being printed now but the exponentail one is kinda weird...I mean something is not right here because it's not adjusting to the points od diagram but it's being printed way further.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.loadtxt('dane10.txt')
x = a[:,[1]]
y = a[:,[0]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)

c = np.hstack([x, np.ones(x.shape)])
v = np.linalg.pinv(c) @ y
plt.plot(X_train, y_train, 'ro')
plt.plot(X_test, y_test, 'go')
plt.plot(X_train,v[0]*X_train + v[1])

c = np.hstack([
x * x * x * x,
x * x * x,
x * x,
x,
np.ones(x.shape)])
v = np.linalg.pinv(c) @ y
plt.plot(v[0]*X_train*X_train*X_train*X_train  + v[1]*X_train*X_train*X_train 
+ 
v[2]*X_train*X_train + v[3]*X_train +v[4])

plt.show()
```

Comment: When using `@` (matrix multiplication), the last dimension of `np.linalg.pinv(c)` has to match the first dimension (2nd to the last) of `y`.  Judging from the code, and error message I'd say `y` has shape (53,1) (check that?).  What's the shape of `c`?  (71,?)?  When running code like this, you should have a clear idea of what the dimensions are for each variable at each line.  Without that, you'll be chasing dimension errors like this all day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently happens when you multiply `X_train * X_train`.
Since it is not a square matrix, it can not be multiplied by itself. Do you just need to raise each number in X_train to 2d-4th power? In that case use [numpy.multiply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html)

Comment: Well, I guess so, but it didn't help in my case :(. Also I've edited line number this error pertains to. It refers to  v = np.linalg.pinv(c) @ y

Comment: what are the shapes of c and y? Where does 53 come from?

Comment: ok, i figured out about which X_train you were talking about and it kind of helped because now I could see both functions on printed diagram, however, the second one is going way further than the linear one...as for the 53 it comes from the split for train and test data (test_size=0.33)

Comment: I've also changed these proportions to test_size=0.9 and it looks better but I'm still not convinced that this done like it should, but maybe I'll ask my teacher about this one...